# Take /rosout or /rosout_agg from bag play back or live and print to stdout as if running locally?

Tags: ros, rosout

Is there a utility node that can subscribe to /rosout_agg or /rosout and print the message to the current stdout using ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT, have it look the same as if I would have rosrun/launched it from that terminal?

I think ros_comm [clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/rosout.py](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/rosout.py) and [tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/roslogging.py](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/roslogging.py)  show all the functionality needed but don't necessarily make it easy to import and use outside of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function pulled from a fork of ros_comm function format_msg that only exists in this ros_comm branch https://github.com/lucasw/ros_comm/blob/salsa_noetic_aggregated/tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/roslogging.py#L235, it's adapted from the [upsteram RosStreamHandler](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/roslogging.py#L230-L293)

```
def format_msg(record_message, thread, name, pathname,
               lineno, funcName, levelname, levelno,
               extra_time):
    level, color = _logging_to_rospy_names[levelname]
    msg = os.environ.get(
        'ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT', '[${severity}] [${time}]: ${message}')
    msg = msg.replace('${severity}', level)
    msg = msg.replace('${message}', str(record_message))
    msg = msg.replace('${walltime}', '%.3f' % time.time())

    while '${walltime:' in msg:
        tag_end_index = msg.index('${walltime:') + len('${walltime:')
        time_format = msg[tag_end_index: msg.index('}', tag_end_index)]
        time_str = time.strftime(time_format)
        msg = msg.replace('${walltime:' + time_format + '}', time_str)

    msg = msg.replace('${thread}', str(thread))
    msg = msg.replace('${logger}', str(name))
    msg = msg.replace('${file}', str(pathname))
    msg = msg.replace('${shortfile}', str(get_shortfile(pathname)))
    msg = msg.replace('${line}', '{:4d}'.format(lineno))
    msg = msg.replace('${function}', str(funcName))
    try:
        from rospy import get_name
        node_name = get_name()
    except ImportError:
        node_name = '<unknown_node_name>'
    msg = msg.replace('${node}', node_name)
    time_str = '%.3f' % time.time()
    if extra_time is not None:
        time_str += ', %.3f' % extra_time
    msg = msg.replace('${time}', time_str)

    while '${time:' in msg:
        tag_end_index = msg.index('${time:') + len('${time:')
        time_format = msg[tag_end_index: msg.index('}', tag_end_index)]
        time_str = time.strftime(time_format)

        if self._get_time is not None and not self._is_wallclock():
            time_str += ', %f' % self._get_time()

        msg = msg.replace('${time:' + time_format + '}', time_str)

    return msg, color
```

And a node script that uses it (which depends on the fork, but the format_msg body could be copied into it):

```
import logging
import sys

import rospy
from rospy.impl.rosout import _rospy_to_logging_levels
from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
from rosgraph.roslogging import (
    _color_reset,
    format_msg,
)


def log_callback(log):
    logger_levels_to_names = logging.getLevelNamesMapping()
    names_to_logger_level = {}
    for key, value in logger_levels_to_names.items():
        names_to_logger_level[value] = key
    logging_level = _rospy_to_logging_levels[log.level]
    logger_name = names_to_logger_level[logging_level]
    # print(f"log level {log.level} {logging_level} {logger_name}")
    msg, color = format_msg(log.msg, None, log.name, log.file,
                            log.line, log.function, logger_name, None,
                            log.header.stamp.to_sec())
    if color is None:
        color = ""
    text = color + msg + _color_reset

    if logging_level < logging.WARNING:
        print(text)
    else:
        print(text, file=sys.stderr)


def main():
    rospy.init_node("rosout_to_stdout")
    rospy.Subscriber("rosout_agg", Log, log_callback, queue_size=8)
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

https://github.com/lucasw/topic_state/blob/master/scripts/rosout_to_stdout.py

```
rosrun topic_state rosout_to_stdout.py
```